# Present month in jQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

i need to get the present month(i.e(today is 24 July 2013) in 0 to 11 months format ) in jquery UI date picker and store in variable

my variable should contain the following result : var presentmonth =6;
how to achieve above ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
var month = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getMonth();
```

It will return a value between 0-11